# Kendo Editor Text Click(select event)

Tags: select, kendo-ui, editor

I am using a kendo editor and I have a select event

```
function onselect(e) {
    var editor = e.sender;
    var selection = editor.getSelection();
    var selectedNode = selection.anchorNode;
    var targetelement = $(selectedNode).closest("[contenteditable='false']");
}
```

Problem is when I click a single character then I am not getting the correct selected node and when I click any text(more than one character) I am getting proper selected node.

[image]

Comment: For each Text or character in Editor we have a htmlsnippet in background and when i click that character/text i want that html

Comment: Can you create a dojo that demonstrates the issue ?